# Problems deploying vue app to aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, deployment

I have a Vue app that I deployed to was amplify. I noticed that if I click a route it loads but if I refresh that URL the page redirects to an index.html page. Please help if you can.

Comment: when I remove the 404 page I get this

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DCDCADC0E8850C9B</RequestId>
<HostId>
Y5blh0YP6wlA2kGGLa4GJ7B9NGRB8nn7xMk5QefuUmt6peLOucdbAj81RgRAlayCW0Jo2o5wLQ8=
</HostId>
</Error>

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by going to the rewrite and redirect tabs of amplify and setting .
Since I was using history mode for vue, had to do a rewrite rule.

I set the source address to /<*> , target address to /index.html type to 404(rewrite)

Comment: This page explains perfectly and gives a good sample https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa

Answer (score 0):

1- try to add a default route at the end of you in your Vue-router to catch everything.
routes: [{ path: '/:pathMatch(.*)', component: main/index/whatever}],

2- add the following rule in your AWS amplify app Rewrites and redirects

/<*> / 200